# Extracting keywords from pdf file with python

Tags: python, data-mining

I have a pdf file(link below).

I have to extract keywords from it and also need have there frequency in pdf file. E.g. `'Java':42, 'inheritance':3`.

I have to store the keyword with their weights in an excel sheet.

Can you please tell me some code in python to do it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gZCnlhwVMBIE0SugUUxDIgQrfVz-cDQR/view

Comment: It would be helpful if you show what you have tried so far and where you are having problems. You cannot expect people to simply complete your task for you. to begin with, have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-file-using-python) on how to get text from a pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question!  Let's convert all your PDF files to Word Documents, so you can loop through each one, and read all the contents of each, and then report everything in MS Excel.

```
Sub OpenAndReadWordDoc()

Rows("2:1000000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select

    ' assumes that the previous procedure has been executed
    Dim oWordApp As Word.Application
    Dim oWordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim blnStart As Boolean
    Dim r As Long
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim strFilePattern As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim iCount As Long
    Dim strSearch As String

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        ' We started Word for this macro
        blnStart = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    r = 1 ' startrow for the copied text from the Word document
    ' Last column
    n = ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

    sFolder = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test\"

    '~~> This is the extension you want to go in for
    strFilePattern = "*.doc*"
    '~~> Loop through the folder to get the word files
    strFileName = Dir(sFolder & strFilePattern)
    Do Until strFileName = ""
        sFileName = sFolder & strFileName

        '~~> Open the word doc
        Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(sFileName)
        ' Increase row number
        r = r + 1
        ' Enter file name in column A
        ws.Cells(r, 1).Value = sFileName

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r), Address:=sFileName, _
        SubAddress:="A" & r, TextToDisplay:=sFileName

        ' Loop through the columns
        For c = 2 To n
            If oWordDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:=Trim(ws.Cells(1, c).Value), _
                    MatchWholeWord:=True, MatchCase:=False) Then

                    strSearch = ws.Cells(1, c).Value
                    iCount = 0

                    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
                        .Text = strSearch
                        .Format = False
                        .Wrap = wdFindStop
                        Do While .Execute
                            iCount = iCount + 1
                        Loop
                    End With

            ws.Cells(r, c).Value = iCount
            End If
        Next c
        oWordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False

        '~~> Find next file
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop

ExitHandler:
    On Error Resume Next
    ' close the Word application
    Set oWordDoc = Nothing
    If blnStart Then
        ' We started Word, so we close it
        oWordApp.Quit
    End If
    Set oWordApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub

Function GetDirectory(path)
   GetDirectory = Left(path, InStrRev(path, "\"))
End Function
```

Test the code above and feed back.  My setup looks like the image below.

[image]